# Python Requests returning 404

Tags: python, python-requests

Essentially what is happening is that the library requests will only return 404, no matter what and I can't seem to understand why and I've probably spent too much time on this now.

I'm wondering whether it is a requests issue or mine at this point and would appreciate some insight.

I'm attempting to GET some job details. Even when I hardcode the values, no matter what it is returning a 404. I've run the request through postman and it works, I've taken the Python extract from Postman and it also works BUT it uses a different library which isn't an option to change to at the moment.

the request looks like this:
note: the variables hold the correct values and are defined holding the credentials as a string

```
url = f'https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/rest/v1/{sauce_username}/jobs/{job_id}'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(sauce_username, sauce_access_key))
# print(response.decode('utf-8'))
print(response.status_code)
```

Can someone please help me identify what on earth I'm getting wrong? It was working and suddenly it stopped.

Comment: can you print out your `url`? i'm guessing that should be an f-string in your code?

Comment: Yes, I can print out the URL, probably passing auth the wrong way somehow now

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using httpauth and managed to get it working.